# Org agenda view: how to turn of visibility of category/filename?

Tags: org-agenda

I am using Emacs with org mode. When asking for agenda view (C-c a), each todo line item is started with the name of the org file the item belongs to, or possibly, the category defined for the todo. This visibility consumes horisontal space, and I do not need this info. How can I turn that visiblity off?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The category and file-name that displays in the agenda view can be controlled with the variable `org-agenda-prefix-format`.  For more information about customizing this variable, type:  `M-x describe-variable RET org-agenda-prefix-format RET`

For example, I decided that I wanted a dot to precede each item and I commented out the more detailed option:

```lisp
(require 'org-agenda)

(setq org-agenda-prefix-format '(
  ;; (agenda  . " %i %-12:c%?-12t% s") ;; file name + org-agenda-entry-type
  (agenda  . "  • ")
  (timeline  . "  % s")
  (todo  . " %i %-12:c")
  (tags  . " %i %-12:c")
  (search . " %i %-12:c")))
```

Comment: Thanks! but when I add this to my init.el file, the resulting agenda will be totally empty for todo's. This happens also if I exchange the (agenda . " . ") line in your code with the line you have commentetd out.

Comment: Then you'll need to add back one or more of the variables -- there are four (4) variables in the default format -- `i`, `c`, `t`, and `s`.  Read through the doc-string to learn more about those four variables and then add back the ones you need.  Pay particular attention to the section of the doc-string that begins with:  "*The default value for the agenda sublist is `"  %-12:c%?-12t% s"`, **which means**:  . . .*"

Comment: When I add all four of them back, as in the line you have commented out, the agenda view is still empty for todo's.

Comment: Should the code be first or last in the init file?

Comment: You could try adding `(require 'org-agenda)` before the snippet in the answer, then save and restart Emacs.  Since the variable `org-agenda-prefix-format` is defined within the `org-agenda.el` library, the library should be loaded before changing the default value of a variable defined within the library.

Comment: I just tried with a bare-bones Emacs installation and the answer works as advertised.  Perhaps you copied only a portion of the snippet in the answer and left out some of the parts you thought were unnecessary?  Everything is important -- agenda, timeline, todo, tags, search.  If you omit part of the answer, it is like telling Emacs set those other values to *nothing*.

Comment: Strange. I copied everything in your code. Then I tested each of the two agenda lines ( line 2 and 3 in your code)

Comment: Thanks, NOW it works as you described! I had mixed things up here :)

Comment: I'm glad to hear that things worked out.  If you're satisfied with the solution, please place a check-mark on this answer to close out this thread.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively use *org-agenda-custom-commands* to apply *org-agenda-prefix-format* to a specific search.  For example to have `C-x a A` display items with Active tag without the filename with which they were found:

```
(setq org-agenda-custom-commands
      '(("A" "Active Tags" tags "Active"
         ((org-agenda-overriding-header "My Active items")
          (org-tags-match-list-sublevels t)
          (org-agenda-prefix-format "  %?-12t% s")))))
```