# Hide category string in org-agenda-prefix-format for a particular category/filename

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda, conditionals

My current `org-agenda-prefix-format` looks like this:

```
(setq org-agenda-prefix-format
      '((agenda . "%?-2 i%12:c  %?-12 t%?12 s  ")
        (todo .   "%?-2 i%-12:c")
        (tags .   "%?-2 i%-12:c")
        (search . "%?-2 i%-12:c")))
```

This shows the entries in my agenda like this:

```
                08:20 ╌╌╌╌╌   ╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌
   work-notes:  08:30-09:00   Something important
                08:40 ╌╌╌╌╌   ╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌
      hide-me:  09:00-13:00   I will see this every day
                09:20 ╌╌╌╌╌   ╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌
```

There is a particular file in my `org-agenda-files` list, let's say `hide-me.org`, for which I would like **not** to see any information about its category (what is at the left of the time column). It should look like this:

```
                08:20 ╌╌╌╌╌   ╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌
   work-notes:  08:30-09:00   Something important
                08:40 ╌╌╌╌╌   ╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌
                09:00-13:00   I will see this every day
                09:20 ╌╌╌╌╌   ╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌
```

Basically, I would like `%c` **not** to default to the filename if some condition is met, ideally some property I could set in the org-file itself. Is there any way of doing so? I am getting started with org-agenda, and elisp in general, so if the answer involves some code, I would appreciate a step by step explanation so I could learn.

- I thought on leaving the `:CATEGORY:` property of the file empty, but it still defaults to the filename

```
:PROPERTIES:
:CATEGORY:
:END:
```

- I thought about using `(if test then else)` in the `org-agenda-prefix-format` variable, but it seems not to make much sense, due to that being a simple string, so I have no way to get the filename to decide on it.
- Also checked [turn-off visibility of category](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/17831/org-agenda-view-how-to-turn-of-visibility-of-category-filename), but that seems to be an "all-or-nothing" approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest thing I think is to add an empty `#+CATEGORY:` definition in the file(s) whose category you want to ignore:

```org
#+CATEGORY:

* TODO bar1
SCHEDULED: <2022-03-27>
```

would produce an agenda like this:

```org
Sunday     27 March 2022
        foo:  Scheduled:    TODO foo1
              Scheduled:    TODO bar1
```

Comment: wow, that was in front of my nose... thanks a lot